# Overlapping custom recycler adapter layouts

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can i overlap layout while listing in custom recyclerview.I need to overlap my one custom layout with other one by one

Comment: you need a custom `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` then - *A LayoutManager is responsible for measuring and positioning item views within a RecyclerView as well as determining the policy for when to recycle item views that are no longer visible to the user. By changing the LayoutManager a RecyclerView can be used to implement a standard vertically scrolling list, a uniform grid, staggered grids, horizontally scrolling collections and more. Several stock layout managers are provided for general use.*

Comment: usually using recyclerview each items are listed bottom of another for eg:if we have 3 views 2 will be below of 1 and 3 will below of 2. But i need to overlap 2 slightly above 1 and overlap 3 slightly above 2 and so on

Comment: this is what `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` is doing - try extending `LinearLayoutManager`

Comment: I am already using LinearLayoutManager  manager

Comment: how can i overlap item views..?